# Extract OFS Image Pdata object and save it as Namedfile on Dexterity

Tags: python, plone, dexterity, archetypes

I have an Archetype content that has field called **file** and it is MultiFileField (from archetypes.multifile.MultiFileField). The schema is something like:

```
MultiFileField('file',
       primary=True,
       languageIndependent=True,
       widget = MultiFileWidget(
        label= "File Uploads",
        show_content_type = False,))
```

And I have a Dexterity content type that has the same field name which is **file** and I want to create a script that extract the stored uploaded object from the Archetype content and pass it on the Dexterity custom content type. The schema for Dexterity custom content type is:

```
form.widget(file=MultiFileFieldWidget)
file = schema.List(
        title=_(u"File Attachment"),
        required=False,
        value_type=NamedFile(),
    )
```

I observed that Archetype's MultiFileField stores the uploaded object as OFS Image Pdata, and for the latter part, it stores as plone.namedfile.file.NamedFile object. Is there a way to convert the OFS object into Namedfile object?

Update:
I have found a solution but I am not sure if it's the right thing.

```
for field in prev_obj.Schema().fields():
    key = field.getName()
    objects_list = []
    value = field.getRaw(prev_obj)
    for f in value:
        data = str(f['file'].data)
        filename = unicode(f['filename'])
        contentType = f['content_type']
        fileData = NamedFile(data=data, contentType=contentType, filename=filename)
        objects_list.append(fileData)
    new_obj.file = copy.copy(objects_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you may want to use NamedBlobFile instead.

Then, have you tried something like this to convert the data?

```
from plone.namedfile.file import NamedBlobFile
new_obj.file = [NamedBlobFile(str(fdata), contentType=fdata.content_type, filename=fdata.filename) for fdata in previous_obj.getFile()]
```

Assuming you have both previous_obj and new_obj available.

Comment: Thanks for your suggesstion but I tried your code and when I edit the content type I got this error, MimeTypeException: Malformed MIME type ().

Comment: want to try updated answer which provides contentType and filename to NamedBlobFile?